# Would excessive property calls in code slow speeds?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, properties

I'm just wondering simply if you call .visible/.enabled/etc through code rather than setting them in the properties window would it slow speeds down for either window responsiveness/processing speed of a method if we are talking 75+? labels and buttons on a form?  Just doesn't make sense to me to have these properties set through code if you can set through properties unless for obvious reasons like to hide a label, for example

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but how do you propose to change those settings at run-time where there is no properties window?

Comment: I'm saying that you can set all labels with the visible property to TRUE rather than having to set them in the code's Load method, for example.  If the whole point is to set the controls visibility property to true, isn't it easiest to just use properties window for the controls rather than having to call it in code?

Comment: look at the code in the form's designer...it is doing the same thing you would so there is no difference

Comment: @criel the "properties window" and the whole designer stuff in winforms generates code. there's no difference between doing that and typing the same code yourself, not in terms of run-time perfomance at least

Comment: @Criel As HighCore says, whatever you change in the designer is coded in the <formname>.designer.vb file. In some cases it may be easier to code it yourself, e.g. you want all the buttons with some particular characteristic to be disabled, instead of tediously setting each one in the properties pane.

Comment: You could just test it to see.  Check out the stopwatch class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx have it start before you set these and stop when your done and spit it out in a debug writeline or similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a very hard question.

I think that the process speed dont have a large diference betwenn the two ways, since even when you do it in the window the compiler have to make the objects and etc. 
So, the logical conslusion is that, the time is similiar.

Answer (score 0):

The form designer file is filled with code like this for every control and component:

```
    '
    'Label2
    '
    Me.Label2.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.0!, CType((System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold Or System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic), System.Drawing.FontStyle), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(645, 9)
    Me.Label2.Name = "Label2"
    Me.Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(58, 20)
    Me.Label2.TabIndex = 4
    Me.Label2.Text = "Player"
```

Unlike VB6 there is no real difference between "runtime code" and "design time code" - designer generated code is the same.  Trying to time it with a stopwatch is pointless because any set of properties you set in the test would be incremental (extra) work.

Your code to set a bunch of properties is just like the code the designer uses, so neither is going to execute any faster than the other.  EXCEPT where you add a special loop to reset the Size or Font when you could let the designer code set it when it was created.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the controls property (visible/enabled) there is some overhead in doing so. It may be minor but when you start doing this with a lot of controls, it might become noticable.  While on a small number of controls, I dont worry about such things, when you get to a large (or unknown) number of controls, I always do this, just in case:

```
If Not Label1.Visible then Label1.Visible = True
```

or

```
If Label1.Visible then Label1.Visible = False
```

The real work in in the PAINT event, this just sets a flag but if your property has events that fire when changed, this could help out more and more.